# Why is my function writing one value in place of another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Vehicle database in a .txt file.
Each line has a different vehicle.
Each vehicle has an x value and a y value (both defaulted to 2.5)
Every vehicle's x and y should be >= 0 and <= 5 (and have a maximum one decimal digit).

I want my refresh() function to randomly re-assign each line (each vehicle) with new x and y coordinates.

The function is kinda working, but in the text file, although each line has different values, each line's x and y value are the same.

I get something like:

Line 1: x = 0.8 | y = 0.8

Line 2: x = 4.1 | y = 4.1

What I want is something like:

Line 1: x = 0.3 | y = 3.1

Line 2: x = 2.4 | y = 1.7

```
def refresh():
    new_positions = []
    with open("Vehicles.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            old_line = line.split(" | ")
            x_to_change = old_line[14]
            y_to_change = old_line[15]
            pre_random_x = random.uniform(0, 5)
            pre_random_y = random.uniform(0, 5)
            random_x = str(round(pre_random_x, 1))
            random_y = str(round(pre_random_y, 1))
            new_line = line.replace(x_to_change, random_x)
            new_line_2 = new_line.replace(y_to_change, random_y)
            new_positions.append(new_line_2)
    with open("Vehicles.txt", "w") as file:
        file.writelines(new_positions)
        print("VEHICLE POSITIONS SUCCESSFULLY REFRESHED.\n")
```

Answer (score 5):

In your original text file, both x and y default to 2.5.

The line

```
new_line = line.replace(x_to_change, random_x)
```

Changes *each* appearance of 2.5 to random_x -- so that's both numbers.

It'd be better to have them default to different numbers, or if it's too late for that, recreate the new line with

```
new_line = ' | '.join(old_line[:14] + [random_x, random_y] + old_line[16:])
```

or even

```
old_line[14:16] = [random_x, random_y]
new_line = ' | '.join(old_line)
```

in both cases the result doesn't depend on the original value in the field.